# json_decode behaving unpredictably

Tags: php, parsing, utf-8, json

I am building a public API in php and am having a very strange issue with `json_decode()`. I am bringing in a large string of JSON that I am dynamically forming and having much trouble in the process. I am attempting to load the JSON object in like this:

```
$all_related_users_obj = json_decode($this->get_related_users_raw_JSON($user_id));
if(is_object($all_related_users_obj)) echo $all_related_users_obj->tags[0]->first_name;
else echo "NOT AN OBJECT";
```

I am finding that this works for about half of the `$user_id` integers that I pass it but not for the rest. Normally I would assume that my JSON was simply malformed but according to [JSONlint](http://jsonlint.com/) all of my JSON is properly formed.

I [created a gist](https://gist.github.com/brannondorsey/5864089) of an example of a JSON file that correctly loads into `$all_related_users_obj` and one that does not.

Using the `json_last_error()` function I am receiving the `JSON_ERROR_UTF8` stating that the JSON contains `Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded`. I still, however, cannot find the errors.

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: I'm **not** reading through all that JSON. Put them through a diff tool.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams do you mean post them using something other than gist? I have also tried http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=json+diff

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I used the link that you provided but the JSON values are different so it suggests that many things are different. Moreover, if I hardcode one of the JSON strings that is giving me issues into my php it `json_decode()`s properly...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your "not working" example, one of the keys buried deep in the JSON is:

```
"city":"Rezé",
```

This contains the non-ASCII character `é`. Chances are that the JSON is being submitted as a non-UTF8 encoding (probably ISO8859-1), which is making `json_decode()` barf.

Comment: Thank you so much. Im sorry that you had to read that... I will use `$input = iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', utf8_encode($input))` to fix that.

Comment: +1 for reading 26,655 characters to find that. Although I suspect you didn't. Still +1 though.

Comment: @PhpMyCoder: Yeah, I'm not quite THAT patient. Pasted into vim, searched for `[^ -~]` to match all non-printable-ASCII characters.